# fecing 'Google_Auth_Exception' wror fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'' error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to fetch mail from Google  through gmail api

while authenticate the Google_Client after receiving the token i am getting this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'' in**

my code is simple using google-api-php-client-master and my code is as follow

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once 'autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(array(
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
 'profile',
 'email',
 'openid',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
 'https://mail.google.com/',

));
$client->setApplicationName($config->social['google']->app_name);
$client->setClientId($config->social['google']->client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($config->social['google']->client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($config->social['google']->Redirect_URI);
$client->setDeveloperKey($config->social['google']->api_key); // API key
$gclient='';
print_r($_GET);
$token=new stdclass;
if(!isset( $_SESSION['google_token']))
{
$gclient=$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);//error occurs hare 
$_SESSION['gclient']=$gclient;
if($gclient)
{
$_SESSION['google_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
print_r($gclient);
```

}

I have checked my credentials several times and they were all correct

would some one please help me on it

Comment: Go to your Developer console for the application. Consent screen make sure product name and email are filled in.

Comment: all were filled properly it is working properly after few regenerate of Client secret but again getting error while trying to list massage      $massages=listMessages($service, $user_info->email) ;    it massages (403) Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration i don't understand which configuration it is asking for

Comment: in developer console go to APIs and enable Gmail-API and google+ API

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem but my solution was extreamly easy and frustrating.

When you copy the "Client secret" in API Credentials on your Google Developers Console **they add a space after the "Client secret"**. Be sure to delete it!

```
$client_secret = "hf83nd93hd93j39dj9 ";<--
```

Comment: in my case their is no space ... it should be sum configuration error in app api

Answer (score 1):

As Mario M. explained, there's an additional space when you copy the Client Secret. You have to make sure you got it right.

I got the same error - `Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'`, but in my case it was due to not verified domain. Therefore if you are creating credentials for a Web application or something similar and received the same error;

1. **Check there's no additional space at the end of Client secret**
2. **Make sure your domain is verified**

Comment: what about localhost?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set the Client Secret file

```
$client->setAuthConfigFile(WWW_ROOT . 'files\json\client_secret_google_api.json');
```

and that solved my problem. Hope it helps someone.